# Slow response for ping to 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows-xp, networking, ping

I have a ping to 127.0.0.1 which varies between 1 and 23 milliseconds. I'm using a VIA Rhine II Fast Ethernet Adapter, and updating to the latest driver version 3.87.0.1 didn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: what OS? I wouldn't thing a ping to localhost would go out to the ethernet adaptor. And why is ping to localhost important here?

Comment: Windows XP SP3. This seems to delay every connection I make. For example, from another computer ping to my router is <1ms, but from this computer the ping to my router highly varies in the same way the ping to my own computer varies. I'm not using wireless...

Comment: try reinstalling the tcpip stack.

Comment: Is 127.0.0.1 routed via the loopback interface (as it should be)? If it is then it should never reach (or be influenced by) your network card and NIC drivers.

Comment: Post output to trace-route of Google.com . See http://kb.iu.edu/data/aihy.html

Comment: Any possibility you are running a proxy or some service locally that might cause such an issue?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have a service running locally that might be producing this behavior.   That is the only thing I have ever seen that would cause a response from localhost to exceed <1ms.

Do this:

1. close all web browsers, bit torrent clients, anything that might be making a network connection.
2. open a terminal or command prompt (not sure if you are using Windows or Linux)

**In Windows**

```
netstat -an | findstr 127.0.0.1
```

**in Linux**

```
netstat -an | grep 127.0.0.1
```

take a look at any connections that are **ESTABLISHED** or **LISTENING**.

Some common services to look for would be HTTP (80), Socks Proxy (8080, 8000, etc), SQL Server (1433), Webmin (10000), MySQL (3306).